# How to join objects but keep bevel?

Tags: modeling, bevel, smooth

I would like to join two objects but keep the bevel where the two objects meet.

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Here's what it currently looks like:

[image]

Comment: Joining the objects and then remeshing them did the trick